# Counting occurrence of specific value in an Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find a native PHP function that will allow me to count the number of occurrences of a particular value in an array.  I am familiar with the array_count_values() function, but that returns the count of all values in an array.  Is there a function that allows you to pass the value and just return the instance count for that particular value?  For example:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7);

$instances = some_native_function(6, $array);  //$instances will be equal to 4
```

I know how to create my own function, but why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 57):

```
function array_count_values_of($value, $array) {
    $counts = array_count_values($array);
    return $counts[$value];
}
```

Not *native*, but come on, it's simple enough. ;-)

Alternatively:

```
echo count(array_filter($array, function ($n) { return $n == 6; }));
```

Or:

```
echo array_reduce($array, function ($v, $n) { return $v + ($n == 6); }, 0);
```

Or:

```
echo count(array_keys($array, 6));
```

Comment: Personally I'd go with the `array_reduce` version, just because I'm a sucker for folds. :o)

Comment: in `count(array_keys($array, 6, $strict = false))` may be provided $strict, if provided as `true` will use strict comparison (`===` operator rather than `==`)

Answer (score 14):

As of PHP 5.4.0 you can use function array dereferencing for the index `[6]` of the array resulting from `array_count_values()`:

```
$instances = array_count_values($array)[6];
```

So to check and assign `0` if not found:

```
$instances = array_count_values($array)[6] ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 13):

This solution may be near to your requirement

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7);
print_r(array_count_values($array));

Result:

Array
( [1] => 1 ,[2] => 1 , [3] => 3, [4] => 2,[5] =>1, [6] => 4, [7] => 1 )
```

for [details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Answer (score 3):

Assume we have the following array:

```
     $stockonhand = array( "large green", "small blue", "xlarge brown", "large green", "medieum yellow", "xlarge brown",  "large green");
```

1) Copy and paste this function once on top your page.

```
    function arraycount($array, $value){
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($array as $thisvalue) /*go through every value in the array*/
     {
           if($thisvalue === $value){ /*if this one value of the array is equal to the value we are checking*/
           $counter++; /*increase the count by 1*/
           }
     }
     return $counter;
     }
```

2) All what you need to do next is to apply the function every time you want to count any particular value in any array. For example:

```
     echo arraycount($stockonhand, "large green"); /*will return 3*/

     echo arraycount($stockonhand, "xlarge brown"); /*will return 2*/
```

Comment: Please, if possible, explain how your code works, or how it solves the question.

Comment: @Compass I explained the function and added an example. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Say I have an array like this:

```
$array = array('', '', 'other', '', 'other');

$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $value)
{
  if($value === '')
    $counter++;
}
echo $counter;
```

This gives the number of times ' ' is repeating in the array