# PHP Count number of occurrences in numeric array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array and I have dumped it below using Zend_Debug:

```
    $ids = array(13) {
  [0] => string(1) "7"
  [1] => string(1) "8"
  [2] => string(1) "2"
  [3] => string(1) "7"
  [4] => string(1) "8"
  [5] => string(1) "4"
  [6] => string(1) "7"
  [7] => string(1) "3"
  [8] => string(1) "7"
  [9] => string(1) "8"
  [10] => string(1) "3"
  [11] => string(1) "7"
  [12] => string(1) "4"
}
```

I am trying to get how many times each number occurs in the array and output it into an array.

I have tried using `array_count_values($ids)` but it outputs in the order of most occurred but I cant get the Total times the numbers occur.  It gives me the below output:

```
    array(5) {
  [7] => int(5)
  [8] => int(3)
  [2] => int(1)
  [4] => int(2)
  [3] => int(2)
}
```

I can see from the above array 7 occurs 5 times but I can access it when I loop through the array!

Any thoughts?

Cheers

J.

Comment: Is the issue that you can't use the array returned by array_count_values()?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You have the result you appear to be after (an array showing the number of occurrences of each value), so what's wrong?

Comment: You can see from the array that number 7 occured 5 times, but you cannot read the array to see that 7 occurred 5 times? Is this what you are saying? I think you'll need to clarify your question!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945199/counting-occurence-of-specific-value-in-an-array-with-php

Comment: Maybe clarify your question and/or use a loop?

Comment: Hi thanks for response it was the looping I have the problem with but user Sirko has provided the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the data you want like this:

```
$ids = array( ...);

$array = array_count_values( $ids);
foreach( $array as $number => $times_number_occurred) {
    echo $number . ' occurred ' . $times_number_occurred . ' times!';
}
```

**Output:**

```
7 occurred 5 times!
8 occurred 3 times!
2 occurred 1 times!
4 occurred 2 times!
3 occurred 2 times!
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1G8rVR)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` construct to loop through the resulting array:

```
$res = array_count_values($ids);

foreach( $res as $value => $count ) {
  // your code here
  echo "The value ".$value." appeared ".$count." times in the array";
}
```