# How to count the instances of a certain value in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, count

How can I count how many instances of this value inside an array?

For example:

```
$array = array(5,5,5,5,3,3,2,1,2,4,5,6,7);
```

if for example I wanted to count how many **5** are in there how can I do that?

I thought I should use count but count counts all the values inside an array and not a specific one?
I searched through stackoverflow and found no such question

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: refer this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945199/counting-occurence-of-specific-value-in-an-array-with-php

Comment: Just curious, why didn't you try to google first? using the very title as a search query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/array_count_values

Did you attempt to research this at all?

```
 $key = 5;
 $cv = array_count_values($arr);
 echo $cv[$key];
```

That's how you get the count for ONE value.

Comment: This counts all items in that array I want to count for one item only

Comment: Anything that you would write would go through the entire array anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
array_count_values($array)
```

reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

same question at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945199/counting-occurence-of-specific-value-in-an-array-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the built-in array_count_values() function, then try this:

```
$array = array(5,5,5,5,3,3,2,1,2,4,5,6,7);

$testValue = 5;
$count = array_reduce(
    $array,
    function ($counter, $value) use ($testValue) {
        $counter += $value === $testValue;
        return $counter;
    },
    0
);

var_dump($count);
```

Anything you write yourself is always going to be slower than the built-in function, and requires more code, and require more effort to test, so (as everyone else has said) you really should use array_count_values()