# How to find the most occurring values from a collection?

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, collections

Hi I have a collection of numbers and I want to find the most occurring number and then the 2nd most occurring and then the third most occurring till 10 and store the result in a array. 
The collection looks like this

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 194
            [2] => 241
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 29
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 12
            [7] => 15
            [8] => 21
            [9] => 31
            [10] => 281
            [11] => 4
            [12] => 6
            [13] => 4
            [14] => 2
            [15] => 6
            [16] => 4
            [17] => 4
            [18] => 4
            [19] => 15
            [20] => 4
            [21] => 4
            [22] => 13
            [23] => 10
            [24] => 8
            [25] => 8
            [26] => 2
            [27] => 2
            [28] => 2
            [29] => 17
            [30] => 4
            [31] => 20
            [32] => 2
            [33] => 4
            [34] => 20
            [35] => 6
        )

)
```

So I want to find the most occurring one and so on till 10th most occurring number.

Comment: You should try to solve it. Then, if you have problems, you can ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting Occurence of Specific Value in An Array With PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945199/counting-occurence-of-specific-value-in-an-array-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

use `array_count_values`, here is your reference link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count_values.asp

```
<?php
$a=array("A","Cat","Dog","A","Dog");
print_r(array_count_values($a));
?>
```

Output

```
Array ( [A] => 2 [Cat] => 1 [Dog] => 2 )
```