# MySql "IN" does not effect on duplicate value

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table as follows:

```
+----+---------+---------+-------+
| id | column1 | column2 | count |
+----+---------+---------+-------+
|  1 |      23 |      50 |    10 |
+----+---------+---------+-------+
```

And a query as follows:

```
UPDATE `count_table` 
SET `count`=`count`-1 
WHERE (`column1`, `column2`) 
IN ((23,50),(23,50))
```

when I execute the query I expect value of the 'count' column to be 8, but result is 9.

Is there any alternate query by which I can effect the query as expected.

**Note: I don't want to change statement like  count=count-2**

A code snippet is given below

```
// this array is program generated ,it can hold max 300 values
$a=["(23,50)","(23,50)","(24,13)","(30,23)","(32,52)"];

$in_values = "(";

foreach ($a as $value) 
{
    $in_values .= $value . ",";
}

$in_values = substr($in_values, 0, -1) . ")";

$update_query = "UPDATE `count_table` SET `count`=`count`-1  WHERE (`column1`, `column2`)  IN  " . $in_values;
```

Comment: Sql is not a procedural language. You will need to call the statement twice.

Comment: Why not just `SET `count`=`count`-2` ?

Comment: because there are other column pair in IN query  at which I don't want it to be  decremented by two

Comment: What is the logic for deciding which rows should be decremented by which amount?

Comment: I have updated the question with a code snippet,
if you look at the array,if value in the array repeated n time,then it should be decremented by n

Comment: You have more or less answered your own question - you need to pass the decrement value based on the number of occurences of an array value in PHP. The sql statement is  otherwise fine.

Comment: You could store the pairs in a temp table. Then use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` in a subquery of the UPDATE statement. But i would probably just run a prepared statement 300 times.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, running a statement 300 times is my last option, but I just want that statement to be executed in one trip to database, not 300 times.

Comment: Count number of occurances in an array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945199/counting-occurence-of-specific-value-in-an-array-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a temporary table to store the pairs. Then you can run a `UPDATE ... JOIN` statement.

```sql
drop temporary table if exists tmp;
create temporary table tmp (column1 int, column2 int);
insert into tmp(column1, column2) values (23,50),(23,50),(24,13),(30,23),(32,52);

update count_table t1
join (
    select column1, column2, count(*) as `count`
    from tmp
    group by column1, column2
) t2 using (column1, column2)
set t1.count = t1.count - t2.count;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/NRXM35380

Note: If you use replication you should read this: [Replication and Temporary Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-temptables.html)

Comment: Thanks,It will be helpful for me,

Comment: can you tell me which is optimized?
  Using your above solution?
        or
  Using a for loop and inside for loop one update statement is executed

Comment: @Onx Probably this one. But you can only be sure if you run benchmarks. It's possible that preparing the update statement once and execute in a loop is fast enough. In that case i would take the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
UPDATE count_table SET count=count-1 WHERE coloumn1 in (23,50) OR coloumn2 IN (23,50)
```

Give it a try, this should work.

**EDIT**

You can try like this,

```
$a = ["23,50", "23,50", "24,13", "30,23", "32,52"];
$column1 = $column2 = [];
foreach ($a as $v){
    $temp = explode(',',$v);
    $column1[] = $temp[0];
    $column2[] = $temp[1];
}
$update_query = "UPDATE `count_table` SET `count`=`count`-1    
WHERE coloumn1` IN  (".implode(',', $column1).")   
OR coloumn2` IN  (".implode(',', $column2).")";
```

Comment: I want exact condition  by combining coloumn1,coloumn2 , not separately

Comment: As per your syntax its not possible, tell me requirement, I will give you alternative for the same

Comment: IN ((23,50),(23,50))

Above value are stored in array by fetching from database,
I just loop throgh the array and build the In SQL query

Comment: Mate, I am asking, do you need column1 in range of 23 to 50 and column2 in range of 23 to 50, is it ?

Comment: NO, I want exactly the row coloumn1=23 and colomn2=50

Comment: You means every first index of every array element you gave will be checked with column1 and second with column2 right ?

Comment: I have update the question with code snippet, kindly check

Comment: your code will not work, I have already said coloumn1 and coloumn2 to be in AND condition,not separately, Kindly try to  Understand the  question