# How to check if a specific key and value exist more than 3 times in php array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have following 'challange';

I have array like this:

```
Array
(

[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 94
        [day] => Monday
        [date] => 2018-07-09
        [week_number] => 2
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 95
        [day] => Tuesday
        [date] => 2018-07-10
        [week_number] => 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 83
        [day] => Saturday
        [date] => 2018-07-07
        [week_number] => 1
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 82
        [day] => Friday
        [date] => 2018-07-06
        [week_number] => 1
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 81
        [day] => Thursday
        [date] => 2018-07-05
        [week_number] => 1
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 80
        [day] => Wednesday
        [date] => 2018-07-04
        [week_number] => 1
    )

)
```

I wanted to know how many times user have selected "week_number" 1,2 and so on, I don't want to allow user to select more than 3 events in a week.

I am using fullcalendar to display events.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Solid answer with most upvotes (not accepted) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945199/counting-occurrence-of-specific-value-in-an-array-with-php

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: what did you research or try so far? Examine each piece of data, and check its week number. Keep a count of how many times each week number appears. If the  threshold is exceeded for any given week number, then invalidate the submission. The logic is not too hard...

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7 you can extract the `week_number` properties and count the values:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'week_number'));
```

Will yield the `week_number` as the key and the count as the value:

```
array
(
       [1] => 4
       [2] => 2
)
```

Depending upon wheteher you want to check for multiples or just one, loop and check for `> 3` or use `in_array(3, $result)`.

Comment: Input is array of objects not array of arrays.

Comment: @Pyton: I know, as stated,  **In PHP 7 you can**

Answer (score 0):

You might use `array_reduce` to

```
$result = array_reduce($input, function($outpu, $item) {
    if(!isset($output[$item->week_number])) {
        $output[$item->week_number] = 0;
    }
    return $output[$item->week_number]++;
});

var_dump($result);
```

Where `$input` is You array of objects

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check if there are more than x events, and you don't need to count all events, better use something like this:

```
function hasTooManySelections($items, $maxSelections = 3)
{
    $counts = [];

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $counts[$item->week_number] = isset($counts[$item->week_number]) ? $counts[$item->week_number] + 1 : 1;

        if ($counts[$item->week_number] > $maxSelections) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(hasTooManySelections($items));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/XbiH0

Answer (score -1):

You can sort your array in respect of group by week number and then count length of all perticular group